# Atualizar valor no banco de dados quando alterado valor da célula no DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou usando uma database local mesmo, criada por uma classe Banco e gostaria que quando eu alterasse valores nas células do DataGridView na tela de Cadastrar Clientes, esse mesmo valor fosse alterado em uma outra tela, no caso eu tenho uma tela de Cadastro de Patrimônios onde Cliente é uma coluna do DataGridView dos meus patrimônios que puxa o nome do cliente cadastrado anteriormente e preciso que o valor dessa coluna fosse alterado junto.

```
using Patronum.Negocio;
using Patronum.Negocio.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Patronum.Negocio.Persistencia;

namespace Patronum.Grafico {
  public partial class CadastrarCliente: Form {
    Cliente ClienteSelecionado {
      get;
      set;
    }

    public CadastrarCliente() {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      Cliente cliente = new Cliente();

      cliente.NomeCliente = tbCliente.Text;
      cliente.SetorCliente = tbSetor.Text;
      cliente.Endereco = tbEndereco.Text;
      cliente.CNPJ = tbCnpj.Text;
      cliente.Email = tbEmail.Text;
      cliente.Telefone = tbTelefone.Text;
      cliente.Resp = tbResp.Text;

      Validacao validacao = new Validacao();

      validacao = Program.Gerenciador.CadastrarCliente(cliente);

      if (!validacao.Valido) {
        String mensagemValidacao = "";
        foreach(var chave in validacao.Mensagens.Keys) {
          String msg = validacao.Mensagens[chave];
          mensagemValidacao += msg;
          mensagemValidacao += Environment.NewLine;

        }
        MessageBox.Show(mensagemValidacao);
      } else {
        MessageBox.Show("Cliente salvo com sucesso!");

      }
      CarregarClientes();
    }

    private void btFechar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      this.Close();
    }

    private void btRemover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if (VerificarSelecao()) {
        DialogResult resultado = MessageBox.Show("Tem certeza que deseja remover esse Cliente da lista ?", "Você está prestes a remover o cliente selecionado", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        if (resultado == DialogResult.OK) {
          Cliente clienteSelecionado = (Cliente) dgClientes.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
          var validacao = Program.Gerenciador.RemoverCliente(clienteSelecionado);
          if (validacao.Valido) {
            MessageBox.Show("Cliente removido com sucesso!");
          } else {
            MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao remover esse patrimônio!");
          }
          CarregarClientes();
        }
      }
    }

    private void CarregarClientes() {
      dgClientes.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      List < Cliente > clientes = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsClientes();
      dgClientes.DataSource = clientes;
    }

    private bool VerificarSelecao() {
      if (dgClientes.SelectedRows.Count <= 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Selecione uma linha");
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }

    private void CadastrarCliente_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      CarregarClientes();
    }

    private void CadastrarCliente_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e) {
      CarregarClientes();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      var filtro = tbFiltroCliente.Text;
      dgClientes.DataSource = Program.Gerenciador.TodosOsClientes().Where(m => m.NomeCliente == filtro).ToList();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      CarregarClientes();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ou se for facilitar pode ser através de um botão que atualize o meu banco, lembrando que está descartada a possibilidade de usar um MySqlClient

Comment: Me parece que está faltando você persistir os dados no banco

Comment: Consegue me ajudar com o código ?

Comment: Assim como você tem um `.CadastrarCliente()` você precisa de um `.AtualizarCliente()`, após isso você pode disparar eventos ao editar uma célula linha ou até mesmo um botão salvar que vai persistir todas as alterações da grid

Comment: Entendi, obrigado ! Vou pesquisar sobre.